# Form page fixed height and responsiveness

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have the following layout I need to solve

I understand that the whole idea of the responsive design is to leave the height to adjust to the content, but for this particular work the customer wants it this way no matter how I have to figure it out but I'm struggling hard to achieve it

In my mockup I have a 100% height and weight body, and then a container taking 85% height of the body size.

Inside that container there are the following elements:

> 1. A Top div container with the company logo
> 2. A Progress bar with a step number
> 3. A small div with some instructions for the current step
> 4. A Div containing the form elements that the user has to fill
> 5. A bottom div with 2 navigation buttons

The content should be always visible no matter the device used (see image below)
Number 4. has a inner scrollbar with `overflow-y` because that content will change

[image]

In order to do this i set heights in percentage (%) for each div within the container, however I need some padding for the elements, but when the browser resizes or the device changes height and width the elements overlap each other

I don't want to rely on a bunch of media queries to fix this. I wonder if anyone can find an approach or some reference for this since i can't seem to find it

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: how to achieve that using pure css and percentage units?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use many media queries, I think you should use Jquery (or Javascript) like this:

- Fixed height of all `div` except `FORM CONTENT` (include padding, margin, border with `box-sizing: border-box`). You can use some media queries for best style.
- Use Jquery to calculate height of `FORM CONTENT` (this is scrollable content)

Example:

```
$('#form-content').height($(window).height() - X);

// With X = total height of other divs includes margin, padding, border
```

Call this script in `$(document).ready(...)`  and `$(window).resize(...)`

Hope this help.